# Multi Join + Groub By, get 1 row per album with max rating

Tags: mysql, join, max, average

im trying to make a chart list and i use the following query

```
SELECT 
    vmm_user.username, 
    vmm_songs.*, 
    vmm_albums.desc, 
    vmm_albums.release, 
    vmm_albums.name, 
    AVG(vmm_songrating.rating) AS ratingavg,
    COUNT(vmm_songrating.id) AS ratingcount
FROM 
    vmm_songs 
LEFT JOIN 
    vmm_user 
ON 
    vmm_songs.userid=vmm_user.id 
LEFT JOIN 
    vmm_albums 
ON 
    vmm_songs.albumid=vmm_albums.id 
LEFT JOIN  
    vmm_songrating  
ON 
    vmm_songs.id=vmm_songrating.songid 
GROUP BY 
    vmm_songs.id
HAVING 
    COUNT(vmm_songrating.id) >= 2 
ORDER BY
    AVG(vmm_songrating.rating) DESC
LIMIT 
    10
```

As you can see i get every entry with at least 2 ratings but i only want to show the songs with the max average rating and minimum 2 ratings per album

i tried to add something like

```
MAX(AVG(vmm_songrating.rating))
```

in the having clause but it didnt work

i use php and mysql

Thanks for helping

EDIT 3:
mysql fiddle
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/677cf/1/0

just want the first 3 rows (song with highest rating from the album)

Comment: To clarify, you're rating by song, but you want the best rated album?

Comment: oh no, i want the song with the best rating from the album, the charts show the songs with the best rating but max. 1 song per album

Comment: So you want to show multiple albums, but only the best song per album.  That's tricky.  I need to think how I've done this before.  I'm sure it involved a subquery.

Comment: right, i'm not that good at mysql to solve this by myself :/ take your time :)

Comment: Can you provide sample data and desired output?

Comment: Consider providing a sqlfiddle of same.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below..

```
SELECT MAX(songs.ratingavg), [Other Columns]  
FROM (  
SELECT 
        vmm_user.username, 
        vmm_songs.*, 
        vmm_albums.desc, 
        vmm_albums.release, 
        vmm_albums.name, 
        AVG(vmm_songrating.rating) AS ratingavg,
        COUNT(vmm_songrating.id) AS ratingcount
    FROM 
        vmm_songs 
    LEFT JOIN 
        vmm_user 
    ON 
        vmm_songs.userid=vmm_user.id 
    LEFT JOIN 
        vmm_albums 
    ON 
        vmm_songs.albumid=vmm_albums.id 
    LEFT JOIN  
        vmm_songrating  
    ON 
        vmm_songs.id=vmm_songrating.songid 
    GROUP BY 
        vmm_songs.id
    HAVING 
        COUNT(vmm_songrating.id) >= 2 
    ORDER BY
        AVG(vmm_songrating.rating) DESC
    LIMIT 
        10 ) AS songs
```

Comment: it only shows 1 rating, but i want all songs with and, max. 1 song per album and the song with the highest rating :/ Edited my start post, added a sqlfiddle link